# Which wallets lets you generate multiple ethereum addresses?

Tags: wallets, addresses, privacy

Is there a wallet that lets you generate multiple ethereum wallet addresses? I don't like the fact that I only use one address and that everyone can see what I have. Or are there other ways to keep our privacy when making transactions with Ethereum? Is there a EIP to enable multiple addresses from one seed key like bitcoin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple address from the same mnemonic in Ethereum just like with Bitcoin, many wallets support this (Metamask, Cipher, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on flygoing's answer. **ALL** Ethereum wallets that are **HD(Hierarchical Deterministic)** can generate public addresses for you to use from your private key.

Since you are ambivalent about which address you are talking about, I would assume you mean *Public addresses*.

The overview is that if you have an HD wallet with a private key, you can use it to **generate** more public addresses.

As for an **EIP**. No, but there are implementations of [BIP44](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki), in products like [Light Wallet](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/84), with changed Paths for example as to make it more suited to Ethereum(i.e, eliminating the change path)